# blogdown - R plots get overwritten by latest document

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I have several `foo.Rmd` documents, each one in a different `content/lectures/bar/` folder, wehre `bar` is `00`, `01` etc.
When I knit these, `R` plots get saved into the same `static/rmarkdown-libs/figure-html5` folder which gets overwritten everytime a document is rendered. This means, that the only figures left are the ones from the latest knitted document.

[Blogdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/dep-path.html) says that dependencies should all be copied in a folder of their own but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Has anyone encountered this behaviour/has an idea on how to fix it?

(I am using the ["pretty" URL](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#pretty-urls) Hugo option)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend that you use `content/lectures/foo/index.Rmd` instead of `content/lectures/foo.Rmd`. This is the default if you create new pages with the RStudio addin "New Post" (Figure 1.7: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rstudio-ide.html). Using `foo/index.Rmd` makes it a lot easier to manage external assets such as plots. That said, what you described sounds like a **blogdown** bug. If you have a minimal reproducible example, please feel free to file a bug report to the rstudio/blogdown repo on Github. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie, I figured that my folder structure might be the reason for this but I am fairly committed to it. It's a uni course website which is not maintained just by me and so ease of use is improtant. While the default forlder structure _per se_ isn't a big issue, things like these add up.
I've hacked a solution by editing [`blogdown:::encode_paths`](https://github.com/mivalek/blogdown/blob/master/R/render.R) (lines 330-333). Maybe it could be generalised?

Comment: I just tested it and wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Figures for `01/foo.Rmd` were generated to `static/01/foo_files/figure-html/`, and figures for `02/foo.Rmd` were generated to `static/02/foo_files/figure-html/`. They won't override each other. It will be easier to investigate the problem if you could provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: OK, first of, I tried to reproduce with a simple hugo-lithium site and didn't manage either.
I then reproduced it using my theme but no idea what causes the diff. [Here](https://github.com/mivalek/hugo_theme_teachR) is the repo and [here](https://hugo-teachr.netlify.app/) the deployed site.
I created  a [dev branch of my version of `blogdown`](https://github.com/mivalek/blogdown/tree/dev) reverting the hack I talk about above. This version is needed because it contains the edits we're talking about over on GH.
You'll also need `remotes::install_github("mivalek/teachR")` to render all files.

Comment: The issue is visible in lecture handouts and the one practical worksheet. Each should contain a different plot but all contain the one from the file that was knitted last.

Like I said, I fixed the problem with a quick hack and it works. I know my theme isn't your problem so feel free to let it be. That said, I can't see what about the theme and/or my `blogdown` edits and rendering functions could cause all figs to be copied into the same `rmarkdown-libs/` folder.